# How to use failed_when correctly?

Tags: ansible

On my playbook I have few tasks, one of them is related to debug step.

task :

```
- debug:
    msg: "File found"
  when: file.stat.exists

- debug:
    msg: "File not found"
  failed_when: not file.stat.exists
```

**Problem**

- When I run the playbook I receive always the message on my screen *file not found* but the file is there ... the task should failed with this message only when the file do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fail the play on a condition, use the [fail module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html):

```yaml
- stat:
    path: /path/to/file
  register: st

- fail:
    msg: "File not found"
  when: not st.stat.exists
```

Comment: @KylianKlez you are welcome! Please click the accept button on my answer ;)